# Реализация функции delete, pos, length на Паскале (Турбо)

Tags: pascal, turbopascal

ВАЖНО!!!
Без использования массива строк, без доп. строки и без использования стандартных функций и процедур обработки строк (и также динамическое выделение памяти бесполезно), также пример функции insert:

```
procedure myinsert(substring: string; var s: string; start: integer);
var
  i, l, l1, f: integer;
begin
  l := Length(substring);
  for i:=1 to l do
  s:=s+' ';
  l1 := Length(s) + l;
  for i := l1 - l downto start + l do
    s[i] := s[i - l];
  f := 1;
  for i := start to start + l - 1 do
  begin
    s[i] := substring[f];
    Inc(f);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Что вы сделали сами и что не получилось?

Comment: Для turbo `len  := a[0]`

Comment: Во первых в турбо в копи , я решил прлэосто прописать цикл от какого индекса до другого , и выводить по символьно , но у меня выводится слово и рядом какие то непонятные символы

Comment: плюс понятия не имею как прописать delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нам понадобятся свои аналоги стандартных функций Паскаля - `Length`, `Copy`, `Pos` и `Delete`. Сумев написать аналог функции `Length`, написать аналоги остальных функций уже намного легче. Думаю в моем неидеальном коде Вы разберетесь :)

```pascal
program strDel;

//Аналог функции length
function mylen(s: string): byte;
begin
  mylen := 0;
  //В Паскале, строка является массивом символов (char)
  //В нулевом элементе которого сидит символ ascii-код которого и будет числом выражающем длину строки
  if (s <> '' ) 
    then mylen := ord(s[0]);
end;

//Аналог функции Copy
function mycopy(s: string; start: byte; len: byte): string;
begin
  mycopy := '';
  while ( (start <= mylen(s) ) and ( mylen( mycopy ) < len ) ) do begin
    mycopy := mycopy+s[start];
    start := start + 1;
  end;
end;

//Аналог функции POS
function mypos(substring: string; s: string): byte;
var i: byte;
begin
  mypos := 0;
  i := 1;
  while ( i <= mylen(s) ) do begin
      if mycopy(s, i, mylen(substring) ) = substring then begin
        mypos := i;
        break;
      end;
      i := i + 1;
  end;
end;

//Аналог функции Delete
function mydelete(Var s: string; start: integer; count: integer): string;
begin
    mydelete := s;
    if start <= mylen(s) 
      then mydelete := mycopy(s, 1, start - 1) + mycopy(s, start + count, mylen(s) - ( start + count) );
end;


var s, substring: string;
begin
  s := 'Hello whole world!';
  //"Hello whole world!"
  writeln( 's = ' + s);
  //Позиция "whole" в строке Hello whole world!"
  writeln ( 'mypos("whole", s) = ', mypos('whole', s) );
  //Вырезаем "whole" из строки Hello whole world!"
  writeln ( 'mycopy(s, mypos("whole", s), 5) = ', mycopy(s, mypos('whole', s), 5) );
  //Удаляем "whole" из строки Hello whole world!"
  writeln ( 'mydelete(s, mypos("whole", s), 5) = ', mydelete(s, mypos('whole', s), 5) );
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогло=)