# Помогите исправить аналог функции Copy на паскале(турбо)

Tags: pascal, copy, turbopascal

Примечание реализация без дополнительных строк
Вот мой код:

```
function mycopy(s: string; start: byte; len: byte): string;
var
  i: byte;
begin
  s:='';
  i:=1;
  while  (start<=length(s)) do begin
  s:=s+s[start];
  inc(start);
  inc(i);
  end;
  mycopy:=s;
end;
```

пример запуска:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в отмеченной области должен выводится текст, но как видим ничего выводится.

Comment: Зачем вы сразу очищаете строку - входной аргумент? Методом тыка программируете?

Comment: Скорее еще не проснулся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибок сразу несколько:

- Вы сразу заменяете входную строку `s: string;` пустой строкой `s:='';`
- Вы берёте символ для копирования из самой же результирующей строки `s:=s+s[start];`
- Переменная `i` инкрементируется, но вообще никак не используется

Исправить ошибку можно если сделать для результата переменную с другим именем, не таким же, как аргумент функции. Наверное, вы можете формировать результат в переменной `mycopy`, в которой он в итоге и должен оказаться.

Comment: все я увидел ошибку
    s:=''
спасибо, проще будет два delete использовать.

Comment: @КриштиануМасса Не только это. При добавлении символа тоже разные строки должны участвовать в операции, а не одна и та же.

Comment: необязательно, я до этого реализовал функцию insert, с помощью одной строки.

Comment: Не понимаю, а чем Вас не устроила функция из ответа на ваш же вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1572119/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-delete-pos-length-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%a2%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b1%d0%be/1572236#1572236 ?

Comment: Есть проблема в том, что турбо паскаль не ABC ,  и обработки функций строк немного другая, и вот в этой строке возникает ошибка
     mycopy := mycopy+s[start];
я могу заменить ее на доп строку(но по условию не могу так сделать).

Comment: В `Turbo Pascal` стандартом возвращения значения функции было присваивание результата переменной с именем равной имени функции - `mycopy := mycopy+s[start];`. Судя по описанию с сайта `PascalABC` он наследник `object Pascal` и ближе по синтаксису к `Delphi` - отсюда предположу, что Вам нужно как и в `Delphi` для возврата результата работы функции присвоить результат вместо переменной равной имени функции, переменной с именем `result` т.е  `mycopy` заменить на `result`

Comment: да я попробовал, но к сожалению турбо паскаль, штука очень древняя и такого там тоже нет, препод мне сказали , что в этом случае сделать костыль  в виде доп строки, либо же сделать через delete(потом реализовать и так как) , другими ваш аналог полностью рабочиий, просто из-за особенной турбо его пришлось каплю изменить.